# javax.swing.tree.RowMapper and org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper

Tags: jdbctemplate

when should we use import for **javax.swing.tree.RowMapper** and import for

**org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper**

? Please explain briefly

Answer (score 0):

The different classes serve different purposes, their interface is not the same. JDBC package contains classes to work with databases, swing package contains classes to work with UI. So it depends what you are doing.